# Problema vista controlador en ZF3

Tags: php, zend

estoy desarrollando un modulo utilizando el framework Zend Framework 3, y cuando accedo al controlador para que muestre una vista recibo el error:

```
Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException: Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "eu-cookie-bar/admin/index/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

La estructura de configuración del modulo es:

```html
<?php

namespace EUCookieBar;

return [
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            // dirname(__DIR__) . '/../view',
            'EUCookieBar' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],

    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            EUCookieBar\Form\UploadForm::class => Service\Form\UploadFormFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'EUCookieBar\Controller\Admin\Index' => Controller\Admin\IndexController::class,
        ],
    ],
   
   
    'controller_plugins' => [
        'factories' => [
            'easyInstallAddons' => Service\ControllerPlugin\AddonsFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
  
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'admin' => [
            'child_routes' => [
                'eucookiebar' => [
                    'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Literal::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/eucookiebar',
                        'defaults' => [
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'EUCookieBar\Controller\Admin',
                            'controller' => 'Index',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ],
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
'navigation' => [
    'AdminModule' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Libnamic Suite',
            'route' => 'admin/eucookiebar',
            'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
            'privilege' => 'browse',
        ],
    ],
],

];
```

Y la vista de mi directorio de archivos es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura de los directorios del modulo]

No logro dar con la ruta, y todo indica que es un problema de enrutamiento.

Agradecería de su ayuda.Parece que no encuentra la ruta y puede deberse a un problema de enrutamiento.

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que tu problema es una carpeta extra

Comment: Comparé con el modo como yo guardo mis vistas y sólo debe haber un directorio index que se asocia a la acción, y bajo el mismo el archivo index.phtml. Debes bajarlo un nivel, te sobra el directorio index más profundo.